# Why do I need to call apply method explicity in a Scala Array obtained from java enum?

Tags: scala

I'm calling the method `values` of a Java enum in a scala program and when I try to get a possition on that array it does not compile if I dont explicity call apply.

```
MY_JAVA_ENUM.values(0)  //COMPILATION ERROR too many arguments for values

My_JAVA_ENUM.values.apply(0) //WORKS
```

Im using Scala 2.9, why this happends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get parens for free in the working case.

```
scala> def f() = 1 to 10 toArray
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
f: ()Array[Int]

scala> f(4)
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for method f: ()Array[Int]
              f(4)
               ^

scala> f.size
res1: Int = 10

scala> f.apply(4)
res2: Int = 5

scala> f().apply(4)
res3: Int = 5

scala> Thread.State.values()(1)
res4: Thread.State = RUNNABLE
```